# Choosing the right controller for creating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Say that I have a `User` model and a `Book` model. A user has many books.
Given that I would want these 3 operations:

1. Add a book to the current user
2. See all books the current user has
3. See all books

Which controllers should I create? I feel like #2 should be in a user controller and #3 in a book controller. Does that make sense?

Where should #1 be? What's the "right way"? The "most OOP" way?

Answer (score 0):

You should have both User and Book Controllers. Here in your case you should be using associations between models to relate each other. For example "has many" associations for books in User.

Answer (score 0):

As a `User` `has_many` `Books`, creating a book and adding it to the current user should go to `BooksController`. I assume you are storing Books in a separate table and the id of the `User` and the `Book` instance in another table(would give you the benefit of not repeating Books which are once stored, which to me looks like the general case scenario here).